# nginx rewrite rule to replace words

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hello I am trying to set an nginx rewrite rule up where we replace /posts with /news, we keep the next two levels that is year and month. Then we need to strip out words like for, a, an, and, at, etc.
(a-|an-|and-|as-|at-|before-|but-|by-|for-|from-|is-|in-|into-|like-|of-|off-|on-|onto-|or-|per-|since-|than-|the-|this-|that-|to-|up-|via-|with-))

For example,
<sub>/posts/2021/10/cyber-security-tips-for-working-from-home</sub>

goes to
 <sub>/news/2021/10/cyber-security-tips-working-home</sub>

I tried the following but it is erroring out

```
        location = /posts {
                  rewrite /posts/$1/$2/$3 /news/([a-z]+)/?$/([a-z]+)/?$/(\b(a-|an-|and-|as-|at-|before-|but-|by-|for-|from-|is-|in-|into-|like-|of-|off-|on-|onto-|or-|per-|since-|than-|the-|this-|that-|to-|up-|via-|with-))|((-a|-an|-in)\b) break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rewrite    ^(.*)posts(.*)$    $1news$2;
```

Best,
Ryan Clark